# i want to create button inside fragment?

Tags: android, url, android-fragments, actionlistener, layout-inflater

i have one class which is extracting fragement and inside this i want to create button which contain some usrl address . how to achieve this ? i tried but it gave me error please look at my code and give some suggestion .

my java class code is

```
public class McaFragment extends Fragment  {


Button button;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mca, container, false);


        addListenerOnButton();

        return rootView;

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); //getting error here in //findViewById

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

              Intent browserIntent = 
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mkyong.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: I gave the answer earlier... and it was correct from the start. But ok...

Comment: i can only vote up now zoran and i did it :) hope you don't mind it ...

Comment: I noticed. That's why i voted your answer so now it's not -1 ;). I don't mind

Comment: hehee a big thanx bro :) you such a nice person (y)

Comment: it seems you also Passionate d about android . if you want to join me on fb ...you are welcome so we can discuss problems with each other (https://www.facebook.com/ramanrayat7?ref=tn_tnmn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant directly use `findViewById` in fragment you need to call your activity's context first:

**sample:**

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

if you want to use the button within your fragment's view you need to pass your view in the parameter of your `addListenerOnButton`

**sample:**

////////`addListenerOnButton(rootView);`

```
 public void addListenerOnButton(View v) {

    button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1); //getting error here in //findViewById

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          Intent browserIntent = 
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mkyong.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: it solve my error but still my code is not working ....run time error is coming .... please review my code and help me .

Comment: hey thanks alot you saved my time :) than you so much man it work :)

Comment: stack overflow is awesome

Answer (score 1):

If your button is in your fragment layout you should put:

```
button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Before that, you should put rootView to be global variable, below Button button. So:

```
Button button;
View rootView;
```

and later in onCreateView:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mca, container, false);
```